# def change method in rails 3.1 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

why does rails 3.1 onward generate 'def change' in generated models instead of 'def up' and 'def down"? 
Do these two sets of code do the same?

any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this article](http://www.edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2011/05/06/reversible-migrations/index.html).

Basically, `change` allows "magic rollbacks" (usually) without having to write both `up` and `down` methods. (Which are now instance methods, btw.)